# LightSpeed and multi-tenant databases

Tags: design-patterns, multi-tenant, lightspeed

I have a database shared by many organisations (a multi-tennant scenario).

I would like to ensure that an authorised user can only view a single organisation's data without the need to to explicitly code such a constraint each time.

Is there a good approach with LightSpeed to do this?

Comment: What do you mean by "each time"? How data from different organizations can be tell from the data from the same organization?

Comment: If I add a method to a Repository service to retrieve a list if users, I'd rather not have to specify that it is filtered by a particular tenant. I want it implicit, e.g. defined in some kind of base class for the query.

Answer (score 3):

One possible solution is to have separate tables for each tenant, i.e tables prefixed with some sort of tenant identifier.

For example, if you have a customer table you could prefix it with the tenant name

```
Client1_Customer
Client2_Customer
```

Lightspeed has a built in naming strategy called the [DefaultNamingStrategy](http://www.mindscapehq.com/Help/LightSpeed/html/T_Mindscape_LightSpeed_DefaultNamingStrategy.htm) which can be replaced with your own implementation of [INamingStrategy](http://www.mindscapehq.com/Help/LightSpeed/html/AllMembers_T_Mindscape_LightSpeed_INamingStrategy.htm).  All you need to do is implement [GetTableName](http://www.mindscapehq.com/Help/LightSpeed/html/M_Mindscape_LightSpeed_INamingStrategy_GetTableName.htm) so that you can identify the current tenant and select the corresponding table name.

Comment: I like the sound of this. I'll investigate this further.

Comment: @objektivs I have just implemented multi-tenancy using this method. Works well.

Answer (score 1):

I've discovered a great feature in LightSpeed called QueryFilterAttributes. I can create an organisational query filter attribute which will let an organisation ID be injected into a query much like LightSpeed's native soft delete.

Very slick.

Comment: Okay, so you have a single table with some sort of identifier that relates to your organisation and you use the QueryFilter to return only those rows?

Comment: That's pretty much what I'm getting at, Rohan.